# @ModelAttribute postHandle

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Currently @ModelAttribute annotation on methods is used to bind attributes in the model. But this happens before the controller is handled.

Is it possible to run this after the controller is handled, but before the view is rendered?

I know that this is possible using an interceptor, but it will be nice to be able to do this only for a specific controller and to have the all the code/configuration in one place.

Comment: Can you try using AOP on the conroller level?

Comment: I rather use an interceptor than going down on the AOP route. I don't think AOP should be used for things like this.

Comment: I might disagree with your thoughts on AOP usage. If your ok with interceptor, please go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

*The below codes will not contain any new technical knowledge for you. But I'm posting the code to make this an answer understandable for others in future for reference.*

**No you cant. `@ModelAttribute` is called prior to the controller action**. But you can do something like manually overriding the attribute by calling the `@ModelAttribute` function inside the controller action code.

```
@ModelAttribute("mySessions")
public Iterable<Session> mySessions(){
    return sessionService.findByUser(profileService.me());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index(Model model){
    // Your Code .......... 
    model.addAttribute("mySessions", mySessions());
    return "system/home/index";
}
```

If the model is used only in a single controller action, then preferred method is to remove the `@ModelAttribute` as a whole and use Model parameter in that specific action.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index(Model model){
    // Your Code .......... 
    model.addAttribute("mySessions", sessionService.findByUser(profileService.me()));
    return "system/home/index";
}
```